# Teradata - Insert statement works for me but not colleague - Invalid timestamp

Tags: formatting, timestamp, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a SQL script I use to import data using Teradata SQL Assistant. It works for me but not for my colleague: they get "Error importing batch records 1 - 20: [6760] Invalid timestamp."

I have no idea what could be causing this difference, anyone know? As far as I can tell, our application settings are all identical (under Tools > Options... > Import and Export/Import). I initially thought it was the fault of the header row but we both have it set to skip this.

Are there any environment settings outside of SQL Assistant that could be affecting this? We both have the same timezone set in Windows and get similar results when selecting `current_timestamp`.

**Create table statement:**

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE Calls (
    Call_ID CHAR(36),
    Call_Start TIMESTAMP(0)
    <8 other columns, including 3 more of TIMESTAMP(0)>
)
PRIMARY INDEX(Call_ID)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

**Insert statement:**

```
INSERT INTO Calls(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

**Sample data CSV:**

```
Call_ID,Call Started,<other headers>
1234-abcd-5678-ef90,2023-08-21 00:04:54,<other column values>
```

Comment: You can import a file, your co-worked cannot import the exact same file?

Comment: You might change the second parameter from just `?` to `TRYCAST(? AS TIMESTAMP(0))` for the import, then `SELECT Call_ID FROM Calls WHERE Call_Start IS NULL` to identify rows with bad data.

Comment: @Andrew Correct, we're trying to import that exact same file. It works for me but not for him. Same situation with different files in the same format.

Comment: Just guessing here, but maybe different date-time settings in your DSN vs theirs?

Comment: @Andrew Do you know how I could check this? Sounds a good idea. Still need to test Fred's method above too but I reckon there's some setting like that that's different.

Comment: Check the driver's DateTimeFormat setting - should be AAA or possibly IAA. (Recent drivers only offer those two options.)